# How can i display data using Jquery append()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've data

```
{product_name: "mushroom", id_p: 13, product_weight: "5", product_unit: "kg"}
```

How can I display product_weight after i select product name

```
 <td class="col-md-7">
    <select style="width:50%;" class="productcategory" id="prod_cat_id"  name="id_c[]">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">category</option>
        @foreach($category as $c)
        <option value="{{$c->id_c}}" name="id_c" id="id_c">{{$c->category_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    <select style="width:48%;" class="productname" name="id_p[]">
        <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> product</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td class="col-md-1">
    <div id="weights_wrapper" class="productweight" >
    </div>
</td>
```

i want to output  productweight in weight_warpper

```
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
     op+='<option value="'+data[i].id_p+'" name="id_p" data-product_weight="'+data[i].product_weight+'" data-product_unit="'+data[i].product_unit+'">'+data[i].product_name+'</option>';
}
$("select.productname").on("change",function(){
    var weight = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_weight");
    var unit = $(this).find(":selected").data("product_unit");
    var span = "<span>"+weight+unit+"</span>";
    $("#target_div_where_to_display_weight").html(span);
});
```

if I add new product my id weights_wrapper will change into weights_wrapper1  i want to output like not sure how to loop this

```
$("#target_div_where_to_display_weight '+ i +'  ").html(span);
```

here is my append

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#add-form').click(function() {
            i++;
            $('#add-me').append(
    +'<div id="weights_wrapper'+ i +'" class="productweight" name="product_weight">'
)};
```

Comment: `$("#weights_wrapper").append(span);` didn't work for you?

Comment: Your html example code in the question is also missing some of those data points that you reference in the js block, so its a bit confusing where that comes from. However I don't believe that impacts the actual question. Just clarity.

Comment: after I click my add-form button  my  <div id="weights_wrapper"> become to <div id="weights_wrapper1"> and when i change it it didnt display in weights_wrapper1

Comment: if you dont mind here is my full code https://github.com/akirawinz/stock-proj/blob/master/ajaxcall.html @Randall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an answer prepared based on the snips you put in the question, which was as simple as one change, but after looking at the full code, I see you are adding multiple whole rows of product selections, which each having their own weight display div.

A few things need to be changed, and tackled. The biggest problem you are facing is that you need to isolate your index used for each product row you are going to have on the page. Simply relying on the overused 'i' is causing you issues, since 'i' is not initially defined to cover the static html's elements, and its reused in for loops, and such. Gets confusing!

The first time the page is made (the first row, with the static html) should have an initial index set for the id's to use. Then when you add more whole rows, they continue the index value from there.

Static first row:

```
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-7">
                ... snip ...
                <select style="width:48%;" id="productname_1" id_index="1" class="productname" name="id_p[]">
                    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true"> product</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="col-md-1">
                <div id="weights_wrapper_1" class="productweight"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

This would be considered row one, indexed to 1. Then when you add another whole row using the js, you need to first initialize that:

```
    var id_i = 1;// 1 meaning one row already exists in the static html
```

Then follow with the other js output where you build another row, be sure to follow the same format as the initial static row (same id naming convention). Substituting "id_i" for the "1", so that it builds the html with "productname_2" and "weights_wrapper_2" etc.

```
    $('#add-form').click(function() {
        id_i++;// will change to '2' on first click
        $('#add-me').append( ... the html build ... );
    }
```

If you will spot further above in the "select" element, I added "id_index='#'", which can be used by jquery, to use the right index number to reference which one of the "weights_wrapper_#" you want to put the weight info span into:

```
    $("select.productname").on("change",function(){
        ... snip ...
        var id_index = $(this).attr("id_index");
        $("#weights_wrapper_"+ id_index).html(span);
    }
```

Comment: This is abbreviated from all exact code and syntax to use and cover. I hope its enough to get the author started in the right direction for their question.

Comment: Its a complicated problem. You are so very close, just got a bit of a mix going on with those id's.

Comment: i think  should get some sleep first i'll look into it tomorrow thank you sir =] Gn.

Comment: It's work and I already  understand what you try to explain for me thank you .